# array.every() works on only first element

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array

```
errorPriority: string[] = ['shippingError', 'paymentInfoError', 'generalError'];
```

I need a function call to be looped on every element of array, but somehow after executing function for first element 'shippingError', the loop stops. Below is the function call

```
this.errorPriority.every(this.getErrorData);
```

And the function that is executed

```
getErrorData = (value: string): void => {
    if (eval(this.objectPath[value as keyof ObjectPath]) && eval(this.objectPath[value as keyof ObjectPath]).length)
      this.checkoutState.errors[value] = eval(this.objectPath[value as keyof ObjectPath]);
  }
```

It sometimes, works on array element, but mostly stops after first element, Am I missing something, please help

I expect function should be looped on every array element

Comment: Use `forEach` and not `every`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: I can change, but any reason why above scenario happens?

Comment: are you sure you are understanding every? please check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Comment: Please read the documentation for every. You do not return anything so it returns undefined. Undefined is not truthy.

Comment: Also using eval is not a great practice. Usually there is better ways to do things.

Comment: Understood the return part, @epascarello - do you any suggestion for eval, because that`s a string I have to refer for a path

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-and-arrays-by-string-path

Comment: every function works differently, it is used ex. to check if all values of the array, let's say have value and not undefined, thats the common case. So you pass a callback to it that returns a boolean and in case if the first item in the array fails on check, there is no reason to continue looping thru the rest of the items and that's why it quits. You should use something different for your case, forEach as it was mentioned above could be a better choice

Answer (score -1, accepted):

from the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) the definition of `array.every()` is

> every() method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test
> implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

so `array.every` returns a boolean. in your code you don't return anything. if the condition is true, you only assign a new property.

the following should work:

```js
   getErrorData = (value) => {
    if (eval(this.objectPath[value]) && eval(this.objectPath[value]).length) {
      this.checkoutState.errors[value] = eval(this.objectPath[value]);
      return true;
    }
      return false
    }
```

Comment: this will not hit every item all the time, op asked for a way to run method on every item

Comment: the `return false` is pointless because return nothing means return `undefined` (a falsy value interpreted as `false`), so don't bother you to return `false`

Comment: @Paul-Marie you're right. he does not need to explictly return `false`, but personally I like to be as explicit  as I can :)

Comment: @laian maybe I missunderstood "I expect function should be looped on every array element" ‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

> The `every()` method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

this means `Array#every()` checks if every item in array meets the criteria tested by given function, and that means the given function should return a boolean value. Since your function does return `void` or in javascript `undefined`, this will be interpreted as `false`. And because `every` returns true only if all elements return a truthy value, the iteration can be aborted after the first falsy value.

to run your code on `every` item you need to use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 0):

You are using [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) function, it will just test if ALL elements of your array successfully pass your function.
So the given function MUST return a boolean (true or false) but you are returning `void`. try to return "true" if your condition is successfull

```
getErrorData = (value) => {
    if (eval(this.objectPath[value]) && eval(this.objectPath[value]).length) {
      this.checkoutState.errors[value] = eval(this.objectPath[value]);
      return true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: changed this way,

 getErrorData = (value: string): ObjectPath => {
    if (eval(this.objectPath[value as keyof ObjectPath]) && eval(this.objectPath[value as keyof ObjectPath]).length)
      this.checkoutState.errors[value] = eval(this.objectPath[value as keyof ObjectPath]);
    return eval(this.objectPath[value as keyof ObjectPath]);
  };

Comment: this will still abort after first element not matching the criteria, `forEach` is the safe way to hit *every* item in the array